# When trying to set up the simulation on Docker, it gives an error: "xhost: command not found"

Tags: docker, ros, rviz

https://github.com/EuropeanRoverChallenge/ERC-Remote-Maintenance-Sim

Using this link, I try to install a simulation on windows 11 by docker and I run "./build_erc.sh
" successfully, but in here, there is an error:

```
lenovo@LAPTOPUKO MINGW64 ~/OneDrive/Masaüstü/ERC-Remote-Maintenance-Sim-main/ERC-Remote-Maintenance-Sim-main
$ bash run_ur3_docker.bash
run_ur3_docker.bash: line 1: xhost: command not found
```

I tried to ignore it, but when I launch the simulation (roslaunch ur3_Sim simulation.launch), the terminal output is as it's supposed to be but there isn't any simulation environment like rviz or gazebo, but it supposed to be a simulation environment. How can I solve this error?

Comment: Means what it says. Install `xhost`; IIRC, it may be in the x11-utils package, but that's going to depend on your distro.

Comment: That said, do you actually have an X server on Windows in the first place? You won't be able to see a GUI without one. This isn't really a programming problem; it's an installing-software problem. (Or, y'know, switch to Linux where X11 is there on GUI installations by default)

Comment: I am not sure, how can I install that on my win11? Is it the reason why rviz/gazebo cannot start as launch file is run? @CharlesDuffy

Comment: We don't do software recommendations here, so I can't recommend an X server for Windows without it being off-topic. You should be able to Google the topic well enough, though.

Comment: @Tuğrul765 yes, that is the reason rviz and Gazebo aren't starting.